# Eclipselink left outer join dynamic query malformed

Tags: eclipselink

There are two entities Person and Address. There is a 1:M relationship from Person to Address. (A Person is assumed to have temporary and permanent address).

The key properties of Person class are:

1. personId(pk)
2. gender

The key properties of Address class are:

1. addressId(pk)
2. personId(fk)
3. gender

The following is the descriptor code snippet for Person and Address classes:

```
public RelationalDescriptor buildPersonDescriptor() {
RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
descriptor.setJavaClass(Person.class);
descriptor.addTableName("PERSON");
descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("PERSON.PID");

// RelationalDescriptor properties.
descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
descriptor.setSequenceNumberFieldName("PERSON.PID");
descriptor.setSequenceNumberName("PERSON_SEQ");
descriptor.setAlias("person");

// Query manager.
descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();
descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().setAdditionalJoinExpression(new ExpressionBuilder().get("gender").equal('N'));


// Query manager.

// Mappings.

DirectToFieldMapping pIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
pIDMapping.setAttributeName("personId");
pIDMapping.setFieldName("PERSON.PID");
descriptor.addMapping(pIDMapping);

DirectToFieldMapping genderMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
genderMapping.setAttributeName("gender");
genderMapping.setFieldName("PERSON.GENDER");
descriptor.addMapping(genderMapping);

OneToManyMapping addressMapping = new OneToManyMapping();
addressMapping.setAttributeName("address");
addressMapping.setReferenceClass(Address.class);
addressMapping.useTransparentCollection();
addressMapping.useCollectionClass(IndirectList.class);
addressMapping.addTargetForeignKeyFieldName("ADDRESS.PID", "PERSON.PID");
descriptor.addMapping(addressMapping);

return descriptor;
}


public RelationalDescriptor buildAddressDescriptor() {

RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
  descriptor.setJavaClass(com.tropics.application.products.domain.costingandpricing.SellingPriceAddOn.class);
  descriptor.addTableName("ADDRESS");
  descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");

  // Descriptor properties.
  descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
  descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
  descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
  descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
  descriptor.setSequenceNumberFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");
  descriptor.setSequenceNumberName("ADDRESS_SEQ");
  descriptor.setAlias("address");

  // Query manager.
  descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();

  //Mappings
  DirectToFieldMapping genderMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
  genderMapping.setAttributeName("gender");
  genderMapping.setFieldName("ADDRESS.GENDER");
  descriptor.addMapping(genderMapping); 

  DirectToFieldMapping personIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
  personIDMapping.setAttributeName("personId");
  personIDMapping.setFieldName("ADDRESS.PID");
  descriptor.addMapping(personIDMapping);

  DirectToFieldMapping addressIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
  addressIDMapping.setAttributeName("addressId");
  addressIDMapping.setFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");
  descriptor.addMapping(addressIDMapping);  

}
```

Following is the code snippet for generating the dynamic query:

```
        ExpressionBuilder expBuilder = new ExpressionBuilder();
        ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(Person.class, expBuilder);

        //Getting the MVSelling DetailsID and the number of Selling price add ons for each of them
        query.addAttribute("personId", expBuilder.get("personId"));
        query.addAttribute
        ("addressCounter", expBuilder.anyOfAllowingNone("address").get("addressId").count());
        Expression addressExp = expBuilder.anyOfAllowingNone("address");
        expBuilder.leftJoin(addressExp, addressExp.get("gender").equal('M'));
        query.addNonFetchJoin(addressExp);
        query.addGrouping("personId");
        resultCollection = (Vector)clientSessionHolder.eclipselinkClientSession().executeQuery(query);
```

On running this program, the query which is generated as per logs:

```
SELECT t0.PID, COUNT(t1.AID)
FROM PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t1
ON (t1.PID = t0.PID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t2
ON ((t2.PID  = t0.PID)
AND (t2.gender = 'M'))
WHERE (t0.gender = 'M')) GROUP BY t0.PID ;
```

How can I write the expression to add the gender condition(char data type in db) in the first join clause itself and get rid off of second join clause?

The expected query is:
SELECT t0.PID, COUNT(t1.AID)
    FROM PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t1
    ON (t1.PID = t0.PID  AND (t2.gender = 'M'))
    WHERE t0.gender = 'M' GROUP BY t0.PID

Comment: why is gender in your address table?

Comment: What are the results of the two queries? They seem like they would give the same results, so what exactly are you looking for?  If you look at your expressions, you are building two separate joins by calling expBuilder.anyOfAllowingNone("address") twice.

Comment: @Chris The results are identical for both the queries.I am calling anyOfAllowingNone("address") twice since addressId whose count() is required is part of Address table in 1:M relationship. However, i need both the conditions to be part of one join only viz. PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t1
ON (t1.PID = t0.PID and (t2.gender = 'M')). Could you please suggest the expression to add gender condition to one join?

Comment: @Chris If I introduce new entity Employee which is subclass of  Person.
The code for same in buildEmployeeDescriptor() method is: descriptor.getDescriptorInheritancePolicy().setParentClass(Person.class);
I have the following code snippet:
            ExpressionBuilder expBuilder = new ExpressionBuilder();
            ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(Employee.class, expBuilder);
            Expression employeeExp = expBuilder.getAllowingNull("address");

This expression should outer join Employee and Address table but it is outer joining Address with Person. How to skip Person table?

Comment: The address relationship is defined on the Person class, so it is a Person->Address relationship and has nothing to do with Employee. I assume you use join inheritance, but the fact Address may have a foreign key value that matches the Employee ID (which may also match the Person ID) isn't a given, and EclipseLink is forced to use the relationships it has and filter based on the inheritance setup. I can't say more on how to get what you want without knowing the full example - write a new question.

Comment: @Chris have posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53419566/eclipselink-inheritance-policy-causing-malformed-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate joins because you are calling and using expBuilder.anyOfAllowingNone("address") twice in your expressions.  `anyOfAllowingNone` tells EclipseLink to create an outer join over the relationship and to use it as the base of expressions built from this one.

Try

```
    Expression addressExp = expBuilder.anyOfAllowingNone("address");
    query.addAttribute("addressCounter", addressExp.get("addressId").count());
    expBuilder.leftJoin(addressExp, addressExp.get("gender").equal('M'));
    query.addNonFetchJoin(addressExp);
```

Reusing the addressExp will cause the join to be created only once and other paths built off of it instead of a new one.