# Eclipselink Inheritance policy causing malformed query

Tags: eclipselink

There are three entities namely Employee, Person and Address. There is a parent-child relationship between Person and Employee (Employee IS-A Person).
There is a 1:1 relationship from Person to Address. (A Person is assumed to have one permanent address).

The key properties of Employee class are:  1. employeeId(pk) 2. personId(fk)

The key properties of Person class are: 1. pId(pk) 2. pCode

The key properties of Address class are:  1. addressId(pk)  2. employeeId(fk)

The following are the descriptor code snippets for Person, Employee and Address classes:

```
public RelationalDescriptor buildPersonDescriptor() {
RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
descriptor.setJavaClass(Person.class);
descriptor.addTableName("PERSON");
descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("PERSON.PID");

// Inheritance properties.
descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().setClassIndicatorFieldName("PERSON.PCODE");
descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().addClassIndicator(Employee.class, "EMP");

// RelationalDescriptor properties.
descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
descriptor.setSequenceNumberFieldName("PERSON.PID");
descriptor.setSequenceNumberName("PERSON_SEQ");
descriptor.setAlias("Person");

// Query manager.
descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();
//Named Queries


DirectToFieldMapping productIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
productIDMapping.setAttributeName("pId");
productIDMapping.setFieldName("PERSON.PID");
descriptor.addMapping(productIDMapping);

DirectToFieldMapping productIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
productIDMapping.setAttributeName("pCode");
productIDMapping.setFieldName("PERSON.PCODE");
descriptor.addMapping(productIDMapping);


return descriptor;
```

}

```
public RelationalDescriptor buildEmployeeDescriptor() {

RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
descriptor.setJavaClass(Employee.class);
descriptor.addTableName("EMPLOYEE");

// Inheritance properties.
descriptor.getInheritancePolicy().setParentClass(Person.class);

// RelationalDescriptor properties.

descriptor.setAlias("Employee");

// Query manager.
descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();
//Named Queries

// Event manager.

// Mappings.
DirectToFieldMapping employeeIdMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
employeeIdMapping.setAttributeName("employeeId");
employeeIdMapping.setFieldName("EMPLOYEE.EID");
descriptor.addMapping(employeeIdMapping);

DirectToFieldMapping personIdMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
personIdMapping.setAttributeName("personId");
personIdMapping.setFieldName("EMPLOYEE.PID");
descriptor.addMapping(personIdMapping);

OneToOneMapping addressMapping = new OneToOneMapping();
addressMapping.setAttributeName("address");
addressMapping.setReferenceClass(Address.class);
addressMapping.dontUseIndirection();
addressMapping.addTargetForeignKeyFieldName("ADDRESS.EID", "EMPLOYEE.EID");
descriptor.addMapping(addressMapping);

return descriptor;
```

}

```
    public RelationalDescriptor buildAddressDescriptor() {

RelationalDescriptor descriptor = new RelationalDescriptor();
  descriptor.setJavaClass(com.tropics.application.products.domain.costingandpricing.SellingPriceAddOn.class);
  descriptor.addTableName("ADDRESS");
  descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");

  // Descriptor properties.
  descriptor.useSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
  descriptor.setIdentityMapSize(100);
  descriptor.useRemoteSoftCacheWeakIdentityMap();
  descriptor.setRemoteIdentityMapSize(100);
  descriptor.setSequenceNumberFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");
  descriptor.setSequenceNumberName("ADDRESS_SEQ");
  descriptor.setAlias("address");

  // Query manager.
  descriptor.getDescriptorQueryManager().checkCacheForDoesExist();

  //Mappings

  DirectToFieldMapping personIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
  personIDMapping.setAttributeName("employeeId");
  personIDMapping.setFieldName("ADDRESS.EID");
  descriptor.addMapping(personIDMapping);

  DirectToFieldMapping addressIDMapping = new DirectToFieldMapping();
  addressIDMapping.setAttributeName("addressId");
  addressIDMapping.setFieldName("ADDRESS.AID");
  descriptor.addMapping(addressIDMapping);  

}
```

Following is the code snippet for generating the dynamic query:

```
ExpressionBuilder employee = new ExpressionBuilder();
ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(Employee.class,employee);
Expression address = employee.getAllowingNull("address");
query.addAttribute("pId");
query.addAttribute("pCode");
query.addAttribute("employeeId");
query.addAttribute("addressId",address.get("addressId"));
query.addNonFetchJoin(employee.leftJoin(address, 
 address.get("employeeId")));

resultCollection = (Vector) clientSessionHolder.eclipselinkClientSession().executeQuery(query);
```

On running this program, the query which is generated as per logs:

SELECT t0.PID, t0.PCODE, t1.EID, t2.AID FROM PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t2 ON ((t2.EID = t1.EID),EMPLOYEE t1 WHERE ((t1.PID = t0.PID) AND (t0.PCODE = 'EMP'));

The expected query is:
SELECT t0.PID, t0.PCODE, t1.EID, t2.AID FROM PERSON t0,EMPLOYEE t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t2 ON ((t2.EID = t1.EID) WHERE ((t1.PID = t0.PID) AND (t0.PCODE = 'EMP')));

The table t1 is not correctly applied in the join clause.

Could anyone help me with what's wrong with the expression?

Waiting for a positive reply.

Comment: Why are you using "query.addNonFetchJoin(employee.leftJoin(address, 
 address.get("employeeId")));" at all?  Try removing it and show the SQL as it is just duplicating what you already added with the employee.getAllowingNull("address") calls.

Comment: @Chris Even after commenting the query.addNonFetchJoin() line, still getting the below exception:
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "T1"."EID": invalid identifier.

The malformed query still is:
SELECT t0.PID, t0.PCODE, t1.EID, t2.AID FROM PERSON t0 LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDRESS t2 ON ((t2.EID = t1.EID),EMPLOYEE t1 WHERE ((t1.PID = t0.PID) AND (t0.PCODE = 'EMP'));

Don't understand why EMPLOYEE t1 not appended after PERSON t0 and before JOIN keyword in the query. Is it an issue with descriptor or expression?

Comment: First, EID isn't the primary key in Employee/Person which confuses things slightly for EclipseLink, but it should be able to handle it. It seems you are hitting an issue with optimization logic which thinks that Employee table doesn't matter, which is incorrect for your mapping setup to a non-pk field.  I haven't dealt with the native descriptor logic in quite a few years, but I'm sure there is a setting somewhere to fix this, it just will take some effort to track down on the inheritance policy class.

Comment: @Chris do you think adding descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("EMPLOYEE.EID") to employee descriptor configuration would resolve this as it's primay key of EMPLOYEE table and foreign key in Address table?

Comment: @Chris I added descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("EMPLOYEE.EID") in buildEmployeeDescriptor() method but still getting same malformed query. Any clue?

Comment: Can anyone help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Left join between two not linked entities (`person left join address` in your case) through another entities (`employee`).

I used JPQL. These entities could be linked directly by IDs, but eclipselink (2.6.2) added implicit join after the `left join`. And referred (in `left join`) to ID from implicit join. It broke the query. I got the exception `"ORA-00904: "T3"."ID": invalid identifier"`.

I solved my problem by removing `left join` and adding `exists` and subquery. I did not need to receive entity from left join.

You can try add explicit join on `employee` before the `left join` on `address`. It did not help me. My eclipselink changing `join` on implicit join. But maybe you are lucky.

Or you can add `left join` on `employee` before the `left join` on `address`. It helps. But maybe this is not what you need.